# PHP error handler - how to get error name

Tags: php, constants

i have my own error_handler:

```
$error = new Error();
set_error_handler(array($error,"catchError"));


class Error{    
    public function catchError($err_no, $err_str, $err_file, $err_line, $err_context){
            print_r($err_no); 
    }
}
```

If i cause error of type "E_WARNING" this error catcher writes just "2". How i force him to write "E_WRNING"?

I wonder, if is possible get error name from this "2" code. Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll have to map it yourself and replace.

Comment: What's the point? Ain't you gonna use it as `if ($err_no === E_WARNING)` anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch ($err_no) {
    case E_WARNING :
        echo 'E_WARNING';
        break;
    case E_NOTICE :
        echo 'E_NOTICE';
        break;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively an array:

```
$errors = array(
    E_WARNING => 'E_WARNING',
    E_NOTICE  => 'E_NOTICE',
    ...
);

echo $errors[$err_no];
```

For all types you want to handle from this list: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
Typically you'd handle different error levels differently, not just `echo` the name of the constant.